# getting xml file to be local within wordpress XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xml

i am parsing an xml file with the script:

```
window.onload = usdfunction;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","sc2xml.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

and for this type of script to work i heard you have to keep the xml file in a local dictionary as the page... you can't use the full URL, etc..  can anyone confirm or deny this?  also where would i place the file so it's local on a wordpress blog?  thanks..

Comment: You can keep the xml anywhere you want as long as you have the correct path & its on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "local dictionary", but the rule on AJAX requests using `XMLHttpRequest` is that the file to be loaded has to fall under the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which means:

- The **domain name** must be the same, including subdomains (so you couldn't, for example, load a file hosted on `example1.wordpress.org` in a blog on `example2.wordpress.org`).
- The **protocol** (e.g. `http` or `https`) must be the same.
- The **port** must be the same (probably doesn't apply in your case; for example, you can't load a file at `example.com:8080` from a page at `example.com`).

So the short answer is, as long as the XML file is on the same domain as your Wordpress install, you should be fine - you could store it anywhere on the server.